# Can someone compile a program for me with gcc-mips?

Tags: compilers, mips

I am close to having root on my DVR device running busybox. I figured out one of the user login/passwords and am able to telnet in, but that's it. I have a drive that is attached which automatically mounts, which I can plug into my PC to add/subtract files.  I made a copy of the bash and busybox binaries (including a few others), and gave them `u+s`, hoping setuid root would give me some root privileges.  Unfortunately that did not work.  Running `bash` (`-rwsr-xr-x`), `id` still shows up as just user.  For some reason it doesn't seem to honor the setuid bit for bash or busybox (or a few others) to give me root privs.

So, I had an idea, which brings me to my question: maybe I could compile a small C program, such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   setuid( 0 );
   system( "/tmp/rootscript.sh" );

   return 0;
}
```

Which, maybe, would allow me to run a script as root.  Unfortunately, after a few days of trying to compile various versions of `gcc-mips` on various systems, I've not been able to do so.  Which leads me to ask if someone who already has the tools built would mind compiling the above code for me. I realize it's an odd request, but I guess it's come to this.

Some potentially helpful info:

```
bash-3.00$ cat cpuinfo 
system type             : Viper
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 74Kc V4.12  FPU V0.0
BogoMIPS                : 324.40
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000]
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
shadow register sets    : 2
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

and

```
file /tmp/bash 
/tmp/bash: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.12, not stripped
```

Any thoughts or advice from anyone?  Hopefully this counts enough as a "reverse engineering" post!

Comment: Why don't you install a cross-compiler on your own ? And, no, installing a cross-compiler isn't enough to justify a question here...

Comment: Jesus! Just chill!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your post won't count as reverse engineering :-(

Anyway, don't expect this to work; your setuid(0) won't work unless the uid is 0 in the first place, in which case you had root access without the extra setuid().

Check the mount options on your drive - is the nosuid option set?

Can you change that setting (hint: mount -o remount)?

You did format the drive with an ext[234] filesystem, didn't you? If it's a [V]fat fs, there's no support for unix attributes.

What exactly does `id` say? Anything about an euid? Like in

```
# cp /usr/bin/id /usr/bin/suid
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/suid
# ls -l /usr/bin/suid
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 25152 Jul 16 08:42 /usr/bin/suid

$ /usr/bin/id
uid=1000(gbl) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
$ /usr/bin/suid
uid=1000(gbl) gid=100(users) euid=0(root) groups=100(users)
```

You see, the special suid-version of id sets your effective uid, not the real one; but if they are different, id should report about it. If it doesn't, the problem is probably your mount options; if it does, chances are your C program would actually work, but in that case, it shouldn't even be neccesary.

If you want a compiler that creates mips binaries, you might also find the [Mips-Toolchains](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains) page helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the thoughts guys. Here's what I came up with in case anyone needs this in the future.  I didn't end up compiling my own program (as above), but I got close. I downloaded a large virtual machine file which already had the tools compiled (but it had errors with my program calling setuid). So I went another route: I grabbed the pre-compiled mips binary from `https://packages.debian.org/sid/super` and copied the binary file `setuid` onto the box with u+s set, root as owner.

```
$ id
uid=1001(ftpuser) gid=1001(ftpuser) groups=1001(ftpuser)
$ ./setuid 0 id
uid=0(root) gid=1001(ftpuser) groups=1001(ftpuser)
$ ./setuid 0 bash
bash-3.00# id
uid=0(root) gid=1001(ftpuser) groups=1001(ftpuser)
```

As they say on TV.. Bingo, bango, bongo.